# Why was Nero able to return to her human form?

Tags: black-clover

Supposedly Nero was turned into a bird for using forbidden magic 500 years ago. But in the present she was able to turn human again. Why was Nero able to return to her human form?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to magic stones, after using forbidden magic, again and again, she turned into the bird and also the magic stones were lost. elves collected all the magic stones which help in turning back the wizard king into his real form and also the Nero. but I have a question of why she didn't speak to anyone earlier in any chapter. she only spoke once to finral.

Answer (score 0):

The curse was made because she turned someone to stone, but I guess she turned back into a human when she brought the statue to "life".. I just went with it, thinking it was considered an "equal exchange".. I have no idea why she could talk to Finral as a bird though..